# how to get proper ApplicationId and AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId

Tags: authentication, oauth, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have created an instance of OnlineIdAuthenticator as

```
_authenticator = new OnlineIdAuthenticator();
```

but `_authenticator.ApplicationId={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` and `_authenticator.AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId` is `null` . How we can get proper values for UWP app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ApplicationId`, as it is described in **Remarks** of [OnlineIdAuthenticator.ApplicationId property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.onlineidauthenticator.applicationid.aspx):

> This ID is not necessary for Windows Store apps.

So for UWP apps, it is always `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` by default.

For `AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId`, it represents the ID of a user who **has been successfully authenticated** for your app.

> If the user was not successfully authenticated for your app, this property value is empty.

For more info, please see **Remarks** of [OnlineIdAuthenticator.AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.onlineidauthenticator.authenticatedsafecustomerid.aspx).

So once the user has been successfully authenticated for your app, you can get the proper `AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId`.

**Update:**

For how to handle a user authentication request in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), you can refer to the **Examples** in [OnlineIdAuthenticator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.onlineidauthenticator.aspx) and following is a simple example in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

```cs
public async Task SignIn()
{
    var authenticator = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdAuthenticator();
    var serviceTicketRequest = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("wl.basic", "DELEGATION");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Signing in...");
    try
    {
        var authResult = await authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(serviceTicketRequest);

        if ((authResult.Tickets.Count == 1) && (authResult.Tickets[0].ErrorCode == 0))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Authorization succeeded.");

            var accessToken = authResult.Tickets[0];

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(accessToken.Value);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(authenticator.AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Autorization failed.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Autorization failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do the authentication? sorry. I am new.

Comment: @AliasVarghese: I've updated my answer,  please have a check.

Comment: zuo I have done the same but I am getting exception at authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync.
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Additional information: The application requesting authentication tokens is either disabled or incorrectly configured. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80860003)

Comment: @AliasVarghese: Have you associated your app with the Windows Store? To use this function, you must associate your app with the Windows Store. For how to do this, please see [**Configure your app in the Windows Store using Visual Studio**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841123.aspx#configure_your_app_in_the_windows_store_using_visual_studio).

Comment: For Testing purpose what I have to do? and what all details we need from client?

Comment: @AliasVarghese: For testing, you can just associate your app with one of your app in your [**Windows Dev Center**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/apps). Just associating with no submission won't take any effect with your app in Store. After associating, you can authenticate user with Microsoft Account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109759/discussion-between-alias-varghese-and-jay-zuo-msft).